# MVC4 EF Inserting Parent If Not Exists, Then Child

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this relationship for my tables. `Activity, Workstation, Platform, Part` are the lookup tables.

I have `ActivitWorkstation` that contains (ActivityId, WorkstationId) foreign keys to `Activity` and `Workstation` tables.

I also have `PlatformPart` that contains (PlatformId, PartId) foreign keys to `Platform` and `Part` tables.

Lastly I have `PartStaging` table that has (ActivityWorkstationId, PlatformPartId) foreign keys to `ActivityWorkstation` and `PlatformPart` tables.

In my PartStaging controller, in Create method, user will choose from a dropdown an Activity, Workstation, Platform, and Part.

In my PartStaging controller, in HttpPost Create method, it should check whether the ActivityWorkstation and PlatformPart records exist or not.  If not, insert them, then insert the PartStaging record.  Below is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PartStagingVM partstagingvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        PartStaging partstaging = new PartStaging();

        if(!db.ActivityWorkstations.Any(aw => aw.ActivityId == partstagingvm.ActivityId && aw.WorkstationId == partstagingvm.WorkstationId))
        {
            ActivityWorkstation aw = new ActivityWorkstation();

            aw.ActivityId = partstagingvm.ActivityId;
            aw.WorkstationId = partstagingvm.WorkstationId;

            db.ActivityWorkstations.Add(aw);
            db.Entry(aw).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        if(!db.PlatformParts.Any(pp => pp.PlatformId == partstagingvm.PlatformId && pp.PartId == partstagingvm.PartId))
        {
            PlatformPart pp = new PlatformPart();

            pp.PlatformId = partstagingvm.PlatformId;
            pp.PartId = partstagingvm.PartId;

            db.PlatformParts.Add(pp);
            db.Entry(pp).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        var activityWorkstationId = db.ActivityWorkstations.Where(aw => aw.ActivityId == partstagingvm.ActivityId && aw.WorkstationId == partstagingvm.WorkstationId).FirstOrDefault().Id;
        var platformPartId = db.PlatformParts.Where(pp => pp.PlatformId == partstagingvm.PlatformId && pp.PartId == partstagingvm.PartId).FirstOrDefault().Id;

        partstaging.ActivityWorkstationId = activityWorkstationId;
        partstaging.PlatformPartId = platformPartId;

        db.PartStagings.Add(partstaging);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(partstagingvm);
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 
Line 243:            }
Line 244:            
Line 245:            var activityWorkstationId = db.ActivityWorkstations.Where(aw => aw.ActivityId == partstagingvm.ActivityId && aw.WorkstationId == partstagingvm.WorkstationId).FirstOrDefault().Id;
Line 246:            var platformPartId = db.PlatformParts.Where(pp => pp.PlatformId == partstagingvm.PlatformId && pp.PartId == partstagingvm.PartId).FirstOrDefault().Id;
Line 247:
```

I know this is caused by the parent records (`ActivityWorkstation` and/or `PlatformPart` records) not exist.

How do I make sure that I insert the parent records before inserting into `PartStaging`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go fetch the foreign keys because Entity Framework is smart enough to wire that up for you. So go fetch the navigation property and if it doesn't exist create it. Assuming you have the proper navigation properties on PartStaging do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PartStagingVM partstagingvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var activityWS = db.ActivityWorkstations
                           .FirstOrDefault(aw => aw.ActivityId == partstagingvm.ActivityId 
                                                 && aw.WorkstationId == partstagingvm.WorkstationId);
        if (activityWS == null)
        {
            // If we get here EF will add this item, otherwise uses the found version
            activityWS = new ActivityWorkstation 
                         {
                             partstagingvm.ActivityId,
                             partstagingvm.WorkstationId
                         };
        }

        var platformPart= db.PlatformParts
                            .FirstOrDefault(pp => pp.PlatformId == partstagingvm.PlatformId 
                                                  && pp.PartId == partstagingvm.PartId);

        if (platformPart == null)
        {
            platformPart = new PlatformPart
                           {
                               partstagingvm.PlatformId,
                               partstagingvm.PartId
                           };
        }

        PartStaging partstaging = new PartStaging
                                  {
                                       ActivityWorkstation = activityWS,  // Set navigation property
                                       PlatformPart = platformPart
                                  };

        db.PartStagings.Add(partstaging);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(partstagingvm);
}
```